# Can Doogee Y9 Plus run AR apps?

Tags: applications, sensors, compass, gyroscope, doogee

I have recently bought a Doogee Y9 Plus. As I found out, the phone does not have a compass or gyroscope.

I wanted to ask if the phone could still use AR apps. The phone isn't rooted, but I might even do it.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/d96b5251) it has the following sensors: Proximity, Light, Accelerometer, Gyroscope, Fingerprint

Comment: Well it doesn't work on the phone itself. Here is a photo: [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/oGS75BuCZe5jxeZV7)